# Publish URL with scm keyword is not accessible which is causing deployment from VS fail

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I am trying to publish the code from the VS 2019  .It is publish on the url : https:xxx.scm.xxx . I checked the publish profile and it is having scm in the url , which is correct (as mentioned in other stack overflow posts )

```
1>Publishing C:\CLOUD\ADX\ADX-Integration\src\Adx.Integration\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Adx.Integration - 202207061539128.zip to https://XXXX.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy...1>The attempt to publish the ZIP file through https://XXXX.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy failed with HTTP status code Forbidden.
```

Even I am not able to access it in the Browser . It states as **Error 403 : forbidden** . The image is as attached:
[image]

But when I try to access the same url without scm , it shows like this .

[image]

I checked multiple stack overflow posts but none of them solved the purpose .I have allowed all IP's in Access Restrictions by stating 0.0.0.0/0 but still publishing to portal and browser access for the address url with scm is failing . Please let me know how can this be fixed ?

Comment: Please state the question clearly how you deployed either through VS 2019 publish window or using yaml code or git deploy to devops repo?

Comment: I deployed it through VS 2019 publish window .

Comment: could you provide more details like your function app is in which hosting plan like `consumption`, `app service` or `premium` and also are you using `Virtual Network Integration`?

Answer (score 1):

**One of the workarounds I did to reproduce the issue and fix is**:

- Created Azure .NET Core 6 Function App in all the hosting plans like Consumption, App Service Plan, Premium Plan and published the function app to all of them.
- Checked the function app site as well as Kudu/SCM Site - both are working well.

**Consumption Plan Function App Result**:

[image]

**App Service Plan Function App**:

[image]

**Premium Plan Function App**: Working for the Premium Plan Function App also.

**But one thing I observed is in the Access Restrictions Page whatever the hosting plan that the function app deployed**:

1. For a try, I have added the rule of my system IP address to deny in the SCM site and checked:

[image]

**Result**:
[image]

**Hence, please check the Access restrictions page of your Azure Function App in the Portal in which your IP address is denied for the SCM Site. To resolve this issue, add your IP address to allow in both the Function App Site and SCM Site under the Access Restrictions Page of the Azure Function App**.